# Find all homogeneous ODE with continuous coefficients with a peculiar property.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My problem is to find all homogeneous ODE with continuous coefficients the such that for any solution $f(t)$ and any $c \in \Bbb R$, $f (t + c)$ is also a solution.

Let $y^{(n)}(t)+a_{n-1}(t)y^{n-1}(t)+\ldots+a_1(t)y(t)=0$ be such an ODE and $f$ a solution.

Then for $\forall c, \forall t \in \Bbb R,f^{(n)}(t)+a_{n-1}(t-c)f^{n-1}(t)+\ldots+a_1(t-c)f(t)=0 $

Does it imply that $\forall c, \forall t, a_k(t)=a_k(t-c)$ ?

If so, all the $a_k$ are constant functions.

Note that the converse is true, hence the problem is solved (with the previous assumption)

Comment: ...reciprocamacating?

Comment: reciprocal or converse if you prefer.